# Bootstrap dropdown with additional button with chosen url

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have list of links to internal wordpress pages. I created bootstrap dropdown to choose one of cities from given list. But I need sth more.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seska/kg7Lpfrw/).
and code

```
<div>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
    -- choose your city --
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Surrey</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Langley</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Delta</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">White Rock</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Abbotsford</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-big btn-orange" href="#">City</a>
```

It should work like that:

- click on button "choose your city"
- list appear
- click on selected city - button title change on name of chosen city
- href from selected city is copying into button under list called City.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your `<ul>` and `<a>` an id so they can be referenced, then add a jquery anonymous function to update your button text and 'href' value.

```
$("#list").click( function(e) {
     $("#dropdown").text($(e.target).text());
     $("#link").attr('href', $(e.target).text())
});
```

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmcbride2010/kg7Lpfrw/2/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. After a small modification I've got what I need. Just two lines:  
        `e.preventDefault();$("#link").attr('href', $(e.target).attr('href'));`